# System.lineSeparator() not working in jdk1.8

Tags: java

I'm getting issue with with System.lineSepartor() method
Using **jdk 1.8.**
See below code.

```
String text="{"+System.lineSeperator()+"{"a":"abc","b":"bac"}"+System.lineSeperator()+"}"
```

When SOP(text)

I'm getting ouput: {

Comment: This code does not compile. Provide actual compilable code.

Comment: Finish your question. You have forgotten to mention output.

Comment: Make sure to use \" if you want to escape "

Comment: Also, it's `lineSeparator()` instead of `lineSeperator()`.

Comment: public class Simple {
String jsonString="[{"a":"abc","b":"bac"}]";
  String text = "{" + System.lineSeparator() + jsonString+System.lineSeparator()+"}";
}

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text="{"+System.lineSeparator()+"{\"a\":\"abc\",\"b\":\"bac\"}"+System.lineSeparator()+"}";
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

A few problems that you had:

- The `lineSeparator()` method was incorrectly specified.
- The `"` in the string were not escaped.

Note: Not sure why you got the ouptut as `{` as the code would not have compiled.

Comment: "{\"a\":\"abc\",\"b\":\"bac\"}" this json string. I'm also doing this same like below
String text="{"+System.lineSeparator()+jsonStringVariable+"}";
sop(text); output: {

Comment: the above code looks good, check if your code is printing { new line and } this might mean that the jsonStringVariable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Simple {
  String text = "{" + System.lineSeparator() + "{\"a\":\"abc\",\"b\":\"bac\"}"+System.lineSeparator()+"}";
}
```